# Export-SPWeb with Where Clause to filter List Items?

Tags: powershell, splistitem

I am trying to export list items to a local folder but I only want certain items, not the complete list.Is this possible?

I have tried to iterate through the SPListCollection with the "Modified" Property but I wasn't able to get the items themselves, just the attachments.

Here is my code:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://myurl.com" -   path "C:\Export\Lists\Announcements.cmp" -ItemUrl "/Lists/Announcements/AllItems.aspx" -Force | where ( --Here I want to filter List Items by Modified Date  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the actual field name for the Modified field which is "Last_x0020_Modified"

Comment: But what do I filter?

Comment: My apologies, I was looking at this from a pure powershell perspective and it didn't register that you were using Export-SPWeb.  I don't believe that command supports piping as it is a functional command not a selector.